# MVC4 - Combine DIV Table with ajax.beginform

Tags: css, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, html

I would like to combine div table with `Ajax.BeginForm`:

and what it outputs looks like this:

```
<div class="Table">
<div class="Title">
    <p>This is a Table</p>
</div>
<div class="Heading">    
    <div class="Cell"><p>Pos</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>Value</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>Action</p></div>
</div>
<div class="Row" id="Row_1">
<form>
    <div class="Cell"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>Hello</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p></div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="Row" id="Row_2">
<form>
    <div class="Cell"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>World</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p></div>
</form>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8LhEb/3/)

But each row is display only in the first column. How can I fix that?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Row divs and promote your forms to have the `.Row` class

```
<div class="Table">
<div class="Title">
    <p>This is a Table</p>
</div>
<div class="Heading">    
    <div class="Cell"><p>Pos</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>Value</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>Action</p></div>
</div>

<form class="Row" id="Row_1">
    <div class="Cell"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>Hello</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p></div>
</form>

<form class="Row" id="Row_2">
    <div class="Cell"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p>World</p></div>
    <div class="Cell"><p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p></div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace cell class from css with

```
.Cell
{
   float:left;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[check example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8LhEb/4/)

Comment: But it needs a fixed with for each column?

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't need fixed width. I've just tested and forgot to remove. :)